# Grails: what is the return type of DomainClass.findAllBy*?

Tags: grails

grails has documentation for [findAllBy*](http://www.grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/findAllBy.html), but it doesn't tell you what it returns, or how to use it.  E.g.

```
def results = Book.findAllByTitleLike("%Hobbit%)
```

is results a map?  a set? a List? a special object with paging and extra features, and contains a collection of Books?

intellij has no clue what the type or results is (it thinks its a single Book) , the official grails documentation doesn't tell you, Google returns no examples (that I can find), so how could one find such info out?

What is returned if no books are found?  Null? and empty collection of some sort?
how does one safely determine the number of books found?
how does one access the returned books?
Are they ordered?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**findAllBy** returns:

- an *ArrayList* of Books, if found.
- an empty *ArrayList*, if not found.

**findBy** (which is designed to return single items) returns:

- a Book, if found
- *null* when empty

If you're curious about object return types in Groovy, you can use the Apache Commons ReflectionToStringBuilder to show you return types:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.builder.ReflectionToStringBuilder
...
log.error (new ReflectionToStringBuilder(results).toString())
```

Comment: Nice.  Shame intellij doesnt have such features built in to find out the types.  I don't understand why the Grails document writers would leave out critical information, nor provide an example from which it can be deduced.

Comment: Is this also true if you specify max, offset etc for pages?

Comment: The parameters for offset, max, etc will not affect the return types above.  For example, if you specify an offset that contains a single result in **findAllBy**, you will still receive a List with one element in it.

Comment: What information do you get from `ReflectionToStringBuilder` that you wouldn't get simply by calling `getClass()` on the return value?

Comment: In this case, there isn't much difference in output. For example, if your **findAllBy** call returned 12 Books:

`ReflectionToStringBuilder: java.util.ArrayList@1dc2251f[size=12]`
`getClass(): class java.util.ArrayList`

One big difference is how these two handle *nulls*. Thanks to Groovy's runtime, you can actually call `null.getClass()` and get `class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject`. If you tried this in Java you would get an exception. `ReflectionToStringBuilder ` works in both Java and Groovy/Grails.

Comment: You're correct, it does. I corrected the mistake in the answer. Thank you!